# Refresh datatable immediately after edit in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using datatables in my angular.js application. In this after updating I need to show the update results without refreshing the whole page. Only the table has to be refreshed and updated with new values. Please help.

This is my Controller.js

```
$scope.updateInternship = function() {
    $("#internshipEdit").modal('hide');
    internshipService.updateInternship(
        $scope.internship,
        function(data) {
            $rootScope.loggedInUser = data;
            $scope.internship = data;
            $growl.box(
                'Hello!',
                'Your details have been updated.',
                {
                    class : 'success',
                    sticky : false,
                    timeout : 5000
                }
            ).open();
        }
    );
}
```

This is  html page where table is displaying.

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="internship in allinternships">
            <td><span>{{$index+1}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.title}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.category.name}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.status}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.appliedDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy'}}</span></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="Hold" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="hold(internship.id)">
                    <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
                </button>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="update(internship.id)" >
                    <i class="icon bb-edit"></i>
                </a>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="View" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="deleteinternship(internship.id,$index)">
                    <i class="icon bb-trash"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="View" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="viewInternship(internship.id)">
                    <i class="icon bb-view"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it not reflecting the data in the table when the controller loads for the first time or are you changing/updating the data somewhere and it does show on the table?

Comment: You could try to call `$scope.$apply();` after you changed the data.

Comment: after changing the data its not reflecting ..need refresh page then only its reflecting .

Comment: Can you show what you are doing in the `internshipService.updateInternship` method ?

Comment: this.updateInternship = function(internship,data, callback) {
   var url = 'careers/update';
   httpService.postRequest(url, internship,data, callback);
  };

Comment: from this service its going to backend(spring ) and updating details

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution :

1. If you are using route provider, you can use

   $route.reload();
2. If you are using $state provider, then you can use

   $state.reload();

And sorry, if i misunderstand your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `$scope.$apply();` after updating your data.

Otherwise try :

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  // Here you should return the value that changes
  return $scope.internship;
}, function() {
  // You arrive here if the returned element before has changed
  $scope.internship = data; 
});
```

I have difficulties to understand the behavior of what you are doing. Let me know if it helps.